# How do I remove the padding between the content of the cell and the cell borders in a table?

Tags: html, css

I have a table with three columns and several rows. First is an image, so all the cells in the row resizes them selves to the size of the image column. With this if there is text in 2nd and 3rd columns the text will be placed in the middle of the cell. But if I want to place that text right underneath the top border of the cell (control padding between the content of the cell and cell borders), how do I do this?

The heading of this post is more clear... than the above paragraph but in case if you need more info.....

Here is the code: (but its MVC razor)

```
<div id="results"  style="margin-left:120px; margin-top:25px;border:1px solid black;margin-right:120px;">
<table style="width:800px;background-color:#e8e8e8;">
    <tr>
        <th>

        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayName("Product Name")
        </th>
        <th></th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayName("Price")
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>

    @foreach (var item in Model.Products) {
        <tr>
            <td>
                <div class="img-column-width">  
                    <img src="@Url.Content(@item.ProdImage.Trim())" alt="@item.ProdName" class="img-thumb-bottle"/>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ProdName)
            </td>
            <td>
                <label>LKR</label>
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Price)
            </td>

        </tr>
    }
```

Here is the CSS:

```
.img-thumb-bottle {
    height:200px;
    width:50px;
    margin:5px;
}

.img-column-width {

    width:300px;
}

.productname-column-width {
    width:500px;
    height:1px;
    border:100px solid red;
}
```

Comment: would you be able to supply some code to go with your description? HTML & CSS to go with it please.  http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: are you using any CSS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use vertical align to align the content of the table cells.
Available options are `top middle bottom` or `baseline`

```css
td {vertical-align: top;}
```

```html
<table>
 <tr>
  <td><img src="http://lorempixel.com/image_output/nightlife-h-g-291-326-2.jpg"></td>
  <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
  <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
 </tr>
</table>
```